# Php file pathing (No such file or directory)

Tags: php

Getting fatal errors on my php mvc project, I tried to require a User class from Model folder which I have been doing in other controllers, but not working on a recent controller I just created called LibraryController. i tried  to paste all the code from other controllers with the required User class, still the same issue, I'd like to know what the culprit is.. Been on this issue for long still no fix..

```
    <?php 
include('../model/User.php');


 if(isset($_POST['add_memory'])) {
        echo $_FILES['library_img']['size'];die;
        
    }
?>
```

Getting

> "Warning: include_once(../model/User.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory" And "Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../model/User.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') ";

I have also tried using include and require.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you are not in the directory you think you are in when the `include()` function is called.

Try calling `getcwd()`, writing the result to log, and checking it.

Alternatively, just pass the full path to your `User.php` file to the `include()` function.

Comment: It showing a different directory.. I'm getting the directory which i included the controller..This could be the issue